# Does repository implementation be a part of infrastructure?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

In a DDD project, I have this structure:

**Infrastructure**

- MyProj.Library (contains helper methods)
- MyProj.Factory (contains methods for IoC and DI)
- MyProj.Data (contains an implementation of IUserRepository)

**Domain**

- MyProj.Domain (contains the domain aggregates and repository interfaces, i.e. IUserRepository)

**Application**

- MyProj.WebAPI

I need to know if **MyProj.Data** belongs to the Infrastructure layer or Domain layer. I am really confused where the implemented repositories belongs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you would have the repository implementation in the infrastructure layer and the repository interfaces in the domain layer.

As an example, have a look at the [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) which states

> Inner layers define interfaces.  Outer layers implement interfaces

[image: Onion Architecture]

In this [simple implementation of the Onion Architecture](https://bitbucket.org/jeffreypalermo/onion-architecture/src), the VisitorRepository is residing in the Infrastructure layer and implements IVisitorRepository found in the Core (Domain) layer.

Comment: Did you mean: Hexagonal architecture

Comment: Actually no, but the Onion architecture is similar to the Hexagonal architecture. Although I find the Onion Architecture to be more specific.

Comment: Well, it seems you are proposing the infrastructure layer resides below the domain model, side-by-side to UI layer. What I've learned from DDD is the infrastructure is common to all other layers, and resides on the top of the project layers. So, in this architecture, the domain core cannot depends on infrasctructure, but in DDD it can.

Comment: With the layered architecture as described in Domain-Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software, the infrastructure layer resides at the bottom. Furthermore the domain layer should be isolated from the other layers, e.g. UI, application, infrastructure.

Comment: When applying DDD on a layered architecture, repository implementations go into the domain layer, *not* the infrastructure layer. The reason should be obvious if you note that a lower layer *is not allowed* (by definition) to depend on a higher layer. That is, infrastructure must not depend on domain. Here, it's important to understand as well that "not depend on" means that a change made to the higher layer (say, we add/remove/modify an entity) must not require changes to the lower layer (I say this just to avoid confusion with method calls or types referenced between layers).